Natural map from tensor product over a ring to the tensor product over an algebra over the ring.
Let $A_1$ be a commutative unital ring, $A_2$ an $A_1$ - algebra via $\varphi:A_1\to A_2$. Let $M$ be an $A_2$ - module. Let the $A_1$ - module structure on $M$ be defined via restriction of scalars i.e., for $r\in A_1, r\cdot m:= \varphi(r)\cdot m$.
Then, what is the most natural $A_2$ - module homomorphism $A_2\otimes_{A_1} M\to A_2\otimes_{A_2}M$ ?
In case the question seems a bit meaningless, here is the context: Trying to figure what the following map ($\hat{A}$ - module homomorphism, as the book claims) is, in Atiyah, on the chapter on completions, immediately after proposition 10.12: 
Here, $\hat{A}$ is a completion with respect to a particular filtration ($I$- adic topology), and $\hat{M}$ is the inverse limit with respect to the corresponding filtration.
As far as progress goes, I tried looking at the result in Liu, there, he just mentions directly, that there is a canonical homomorphism $\hat{A}\otimes M\to \hat{M}$.
This I actually did manage to resolve for the most part: Consider the inverse limit projections: $\hat{A}\to A/I^n$, take tensor product to get $\hat{A}\otimes_{A}M\to A/I^n\otimes _{A}M\simeq M/(I^nM)$, then the universal property of inverse limit induces $\hat{A}\otimes_{A}{M}\to \varprojlim{M/(I^nM)}=\hat{M}$. Again, I still do not see how this is an $\hat{A}$ - module homomorphism.
Help in resolving either of the issues is highly appreciated.

Try to show that $\hat{M}$ is also an $\hat{A}$-module, then tensor the canonical map and you should get a natural induced map between the 2 tensor products.

More generally, for a ring homomorphism $\phi: A_1\rightarrow A_2$, $A_2^\mathrm{op}$-module $M$ and $A_2$-module $N$ there is a canonical map (your question)
\begin{equation}M\otimes_{A_1}N \rightarrow M\otimes_{A_2} N\end{equation}
which one can either give via the universal property or explicitly note the tensor product relation for $a\in A_1, m\in M, n \in N$ the element $(m.a,n)-(m,a.n) := (m.\phi(a), n) - (m,\phi(a).n)$. The map is also surjective by construction.
Remark:
It also extends to the case where $M$ and $N$ are bimodules, say $M$ an $R\mbox{-}A_2$-bimodule and $N$ an $A_2\mbox{-}S$-bimodule then the map is an $ R\mbox{-}S$-bimodule map.
On the completion maps:
The $A$-module map $M\rightarrow \hat{M}$ gives rise (by tensoring) to an $\hat{A}$-module map $\hat{A}\otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{A}\otimes_{A} \hat{M}$ which can be post-composed with the map $\hat{A}\otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{A}\otimes_{\hat{A}} \hat{M} \cong \hat{M}$ given above.
